# Ошибка 500 Internal error при использовании шаблонов во Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

При использовании шаблонов в HTML-файле и `render_template()` в файле с Flask'ом, на странице в браузере появляется ошибка "500 Internal error". При запуске HTML-файла отдельно все нормально работает. Также, в консоли выводится ошибка `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: test.html` Как это можно исправить?

Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', title='Солнечная система', text='Планета', text1='Звезда')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8080, host='127.0.0.1')
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="9-32.jpg" alt="здесь должна была быть картинка, но не нашлась">
    <h1>{{ text }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ text1 }}</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: А где находится `index.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TemplateNotFound` - не находит ваш template.

Он должен лежать в директории, которая задает при создании приложения.

```
app = Flask(app_name, template_folder='path/to/template/folder')
```

по умолчанию - `template_folder="templates"`, что бы index.html был виден фласку, он должен лежать там.

Comment: Ошибка пропала, но почему-то не применяется стиль css и не отображается картинка, хотя при запуске HTML-файла отдельно все работает. Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему?

Comment: @Nikita2431 аналогично настройками и верным расположением файлов) статика фласка - `static_folder`